# FQL description translated

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-fql

When I access the FQL:

SELECT post_id, description FROM stream WHERE 
source_id = me()

The description comes in English.
How can I get the description at the user language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i get the description at the user language?

By adding a `locale` parameter to your API call, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (bottom section, “Specifying Locale”)

[Graph API Explorer example, getting the descriptions in German (locale=de_DE)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20post_id%2C%20description%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20me%28%29%26locale%3Dde_DE)